# How to check if a given list of integers are part of the series?

Tags: python, numpy, math, discrete-mathematics

The series is defined by the following - 
`f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f(n) = 2*f(n - 1) - 2*(n - 2) for all n > 1`

I want to implement this in python as a function where an array of integers is passed to the function and the function will return all those numbers that are in the defined series constraint.

How to approach this problem for solving accurately?

For getting nth term of the series I have implemented the following recursive function -

```
result = {}
def find_nth_term(n):
    if n == 0:
        result[n] = 0
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        result[n] = 1
        return 1
    else:
        val = 2*find_nth_term(n-1)-2*find_nth_term(n-2)
        result[n] = val
        return val

find_nth_term(10)
print(set(result.values()))
```

is the above program right ? What to do next ?

Comment: Well, lets start with the basics....  can you construct a python function that returns the n-th value in the series and make a list or set of the numbers in the series?

Next thing you will need to decide on is limit of comparison.....  Do you need 100 terms or 100,000,000 in order to cover the checking of the input or are you going to figure it out “on the fly”?

Comment: `result = {}
def find_nth_term(n):
    if n == 0:
        result[n] = 0
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        result[n] = 1
        return 1
    else:
        val = 2*find_nth_term(n-1)-2*find_nth_term(n-2)
        result[n] = val
        return val

find_nth_term(10)
print(set(result.values()))`  -- is it right for getting nth term of the series ?

Answer (score 1):

**We know :**

```
f(n) = 2*[ f(n-1) - f(n-2)]---(1)  
f(n-1) = 2*[ f(n-2) - f(n-3)]---(2)  
f(n-2) = 2*[f(n-3) - f(n-4)]---(3)
```

**Substituting f(n-1) from (2) to (1):**

```
f(n) = 2*2* f(n-2) - 2*2* f(n-3) - 2* f(n-2)  
= 2*f(n-2) - 4*f(n-3) --- (4)
```

**Substituting f(n-2) from (3) to (4):**

```
f(n) = 2*[2*f(n-3) - 2*f(n-4)] - 4*f(n-3)  
f(n) = 4*f(n-3) - 4*f(n-4) -4*f(n-3)  
f(n) = -4 *f(n-4)
```

**By extension:**

```
f(n) = (-4)^k * f(n- 4k)
```

**Also:**

```
f(0)=0  
f(1)=1  
f(2)=2  
f(3)=2
```

Therefore any f(n) can reduced to one of these forms :.

```
f(n)  = (-4)^k * 0 OR (-4)^k * 1 OR (-4)^k * 2
```

**For the python part:**
given an integer (x) :
if X==0: f(0) = 0
else:

check if it is of the form ((-4)**k)*2 or (-4)**k then :

in f(n): n = a + 4k where :

**a= 1** if form is (-4)**k
**a = 2** if form is ((-4)**k)*2

Answer (score 0):

The sequence based on the above relation becomes:(for the first 10 numbers)

```
0, 1, -2, 6, -16, 44, -120, 328, -896, 2448......
```

**code for this**

```
def seq(n):
    nxt = 0
    seq = [0,1]
    first, second = seq
    for i in range(n-2):
        nxt = 2*(first - second)
        seq.append(nxt)
        first = second
        second = nxt
    return seq

def numbers(array, seq):
    int_in_seq = []
    for i in array:
        if i in seq:
            int_in_seq.append(i)
    return (f"numbers in seq:",int_in_seq)
```

if **arrray** here is:

```
array = [-2, 12, -16, 200, 328]
```

this gives all the numbers of the array in seq

**output**

```
'numbers in seq:', [-2, -16, 328]
```